# What does number mean in the backtrace?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Does the 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2 indicates these two errors (`EOFError` and `NoMethodError`) happened in different threads?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  2: from /gem/lib/my/project/conn.rb:72:in `block in initialize'
  1: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/openssl/buffering.rb:125:in `readpartial'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/openssl/buffering.rb:125:in `sysread': end of file reached (EOFError)

  5: from /gem/lib/my/project/conn.rb:69:in `block in initialize'
  4: from /gem/lib/my/project/conn.rb:80:in `rescue in block in initialize'
  3: from /gem/lib/my/project/session.rb:60:in `disconnected'
  2: from /gem/lib/my/project/session.rb:217:in `retransmit'
  1: from /gem/lib/my/project/session.rb:117:in `transmit_results'
/gem/lib/rspec/buildkite/analytics/conn.rb:104:in `transmit': undefined method `write' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: IDK Ruby, but that sure does look like two distinct stack traces.

Comment: If you read the text, you see that you have two different errors printed: _end of file reached_  and _undefined method_. Since I don't know your application, I can not say whether these are from the same thread or from different ones.

Comment: This looks like what happens when an exception is rescued and the rescue block raises another exception; when the second exception is not rescued the interpreter outputs the traces for both exceptions

Answer (score 1):

The numbers correspond to the position of the stack frame in the execution stack and thus in the quoted backtrace.

In your question, you are quoting two different exceptions with their respective back traces. By going up the back trace (thus by going from the bottom of the trace towards the top, you can trace the respective calls and their line numbers in their source file. Upper traces (i.e. those with a larger number) have called functionality with lower numbers.

Note that different Ruby versions use a different default order of those traces. Older versions have but the inner calls (i.e. lower numbers) on top of the trace. Since Ruby 2.5, the default order was reversed to show th exception and the inner calls at the bottom.